# Need to define all the varibales for an exchage during the contract deployment?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, exchanges

Creating ERC20 is not that hard.
We can just copy the source code and deploy it on the main network.

But creating an own exchange system for the token is a differnt part.
If we create a standard token now, can we create the exchange later for the token ? or need to define all the variables & methods during the contract deployment? ( variables & methods that are required for the exchange)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an exchange later. Because the ERC20 token interface supports transferring tokens, you can build a separate smart contract later to facilitate an exchange.